# nameError 'model' not defined TensorFlow issue

Tags: python, keras, jupyter-notebook, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I am not sure if I am missing a package or if the issue is something else. I am able to import TensorFlow now that I have installed Miniforge and made venv etc. (not entirely confident in what I did to achieve this but I am able to switch between TensorFlow and base python env. ) I am also able to create and compile a model. However I get no verbose when running `model.fit` and also unable to get the training history from `model.history.history`. When I try to get the history I get:

> NameError: name 'model' is not defined'

I have also noticed that the model is not being defined in Vscode, it just says loading. I have tried setting model.fit() = history and that has not helped either

My attempt:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras import utils as np_utils

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation

model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(4, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(4, activation='relu')) 
model.add(Dense(4, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1))

#compiling the model, mean squared error is used for regression models 
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='mse')

model.fit(x = X_train,y=y_train,epochs=250, verbose=1)
model.history.history
```

Data:

````
'          price     feature1     feature2\n0    461.527929   999.787558   999.766096\n1    548.130011   998.861615  1001.042403\n2    410.297162  1000.070267   998.844015\n3    540.382220   999.952251  1000.440940\n4    546.024553  1000.446011  1000.338531\n..          ...          ...          ...\n995  476.526078  1000.018988   999.672732\n996  457.313186   998.855379  1000.020026\n997  456.720992  1001.451646   998.847606\n998  403.315576  1000.771023   998.562851\n999  599.367093   999.232244  1001.451407\n\n[1000 rows x 3 columns]' ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update. I had messed up all of my environments from refusing to learn what the venv does. if your having similar issue ill tell you what I did.

1. hard reset everything make sure files backed up
2. install python, homebrew, Xcode, command line tools
3. using apple developer website I found a tutorial for tensor flow set up, source to the link below.
4. I installed mini forge with the instructions.
5. before I installed the tensor flow, I made a venv with conda commands.
6. installed tensor flow within the new venv. it worked fine. I saw a few errors, but it was able to run test models found on the web.

that's it. I got some weird errors while running it in Jupyter notebook, but the sequential model runs fine in vs code. I am using apple M1 and tensor flow with gpu support.

apple developer link: https://developer.apple.com/metal/tensorflow-plugin/